# How to remove a small dent in the front door of the car?

Tags: dent, door, cosmetic

Recently, a guy came and crashed into my vehicle's front door in the parking lot. My vehicle now has a small but easily noticeable dent. Is there a way to remove the dent in a easy and really cheap way?

Comment: as long as there is not a crease in the dent, the professional dent removers are able to completely remove all traces of a dent.  If there is a dent, the only option to completely remove it is to take it to a body shop

Comment: During the private beta, please try to avoid non-expert questions. Read http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask if you have any questions. For now stick to the questions that mechanics might ask each other.

Comment: Appears to be a valid question, now that we're out of beta. Has been asked again (with emphasis on 'effective', rather than 'easy and really cheap') at [Dent removal from passenger door](/q/29132/15074)

Answer (score 6):

Suction is the answer. You can buy a suction grip in a hardware store, but if the dent is shallow enough (ie pushed in rather than really dented) a toilet plunger might do it.

Comment: a toilet plunger... really..? shud try it today

Comment: It really depends on the dent, so don't get too hopeful, but at least it's cheap!

Answer (score 3):

Even though we all laughed at him, a friend used the As-Seen-On-TV Suction cup dent puller and it actually popped the dent in his quarter panel.  It is not perfect, but it did it to his satisfaction.  You could also take the inside door panel off to be able to push it from the other side as well.